# What does a bad voltage regulator look like?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I have a 7805 5V regulator here and it has a white like substance on it, kind of like when a AA battery leaks acid. Is it bad?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the part? If you upload it to imgur.com and add a link in your question, we can put it in-line for you.

Answer (score 17):

There's no reason a defective IC should produce any white substance when it fails.

In fact, unless the part failed under spectacular circumstances, there's usually no visual indication that a part is bad. Sometimes they will be visibly blackened if they overheat, or tiny drops of clear liquid will exude out from the packaging encapsulant. Or the markings on the part may fade from heat, but that can also happen just from long normal usage, especially with hot parts like voltage regulators.

The most likely thing I can think of is, if the part comes out of some old equipment, it had some silicone grease on it to improve contact with a heat sink. When that grease gets old and dried out it can look something like leaking battery gunk.

Comment: Thanks. I was troubleshooting an old game console.  That's exactly what it looks like and it was on the side attached to the heat sink.